# W3C-Validation problem with overlapping form and div-tags

Tags: xhtml, forms, w3c-validation

I'm having problems with validating this code with the W3 validator.
The problem is with the `<form>` tag.
I need the `<form>` tag to overlap several `<div>` and `<span>` tags because I have many different input fields and such, but I'm also using the Form2 and Form3 with input fields and such so I need to use `</form>` before the Form2. But this gives me problems when validating because it's overlapping `<div>` and `<span>` tags.
What can I do to make the validation work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="sv" xml:lang="sv" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">

 <div id="headerwrapper">
  <div class="header alignleft">
   <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="header alignright">
   <div id="searchfield">
   Search
   </div>
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
  Menu
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>

 <div class="content">
  <div class="box alignleft">

   <div class="boxtop"></div>
   <div class="boxmiddle">

    <form action="links.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="edit_page_check" value="yes" />

    <p>
     <span id="page_leftbox">Text</span>
    </p>
   </div>

   <div class="boxbottom"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="column580 alignright">

   <div class="header580">
    <h2>Topic</h2><span class="headerdesc">Text</span>
   </div>
   <p>

    <span id="page_info">Info</span>

   </p>

   </form>
   <br/>
   <div id="addlinkform" style="display: none;">
Form2
   </div>
   <div id="linkform" style="display: none;">
Form3
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
 <div class="divider800"></div>
 <div id="footer">
Footer text
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All the sample tags you put in your question are being stripped by the display processor. The question will be clearer if they're escaped or somehow otherwise made visible - wrapping them in ` characters (code block) might help.

Answer (score 2):

XHTML doesn't let you overlap tags. For example, this is invalid:

```
<div><form></div></form>
```

What you're going to want to do is, rather than trying to only encompass the items that you believe are in the form, encompass the `<input />` tags that are in the form *as well as* their containers. For instance, your code should look like this instead:

```
 <div class="content">
    <form action="links.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="edit_page_check" value="yes" />
  <div class="box alignleft">

   <div class="boxtop"></div>
   <div class="boxmiddle">


    <p>
     <span id="page_leftbox">Text</span>
    </p>
   </div>

   <div class="boxbottom"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="column580 alignright">

   <div class="header580">
    <h2>Topic</h2><span class="headerdesc">Text</span>
   </div>
   <p>

    <span id="page_info">Info</span>

   </p>

   <br/>
   <div id="addlinkform" style="display: none;">
Form2
   </div>
   <div id="linkform" style="display: none;">
Form3
   </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

Notice how the form element spans ALL of the input tags' containers.

Answer (score 0):

XML (XHTML in this case) needs to be well-formed. Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element). You should be able to fix that problem by moving the `<form>`-tag up in the tree.

Instead of

```
<div>
    <form action="/some_target" method="post">
        <input/>
</div>
<div>
        <input />
    </form>
</div>
```

do the following (move the `form` element up, so that it wraps the inputs as well as their containers):

```
<form action="/some_target" method="post">
    <div>
        <input/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input />
    </div>
</form>
```